# Function of a function works one direction, not the other

Tags: c#, functional-programming

I'm trying to write a function that takes a function as one of its arguments -- a task I've done many times before.  This works fine:

```
int RunFunction(Func<int,int> f, int input) {
    return f(input);
}
int Double(int x) {
    return x*2;
}

// somewhere else in code
RunFunction(Double,5);
```

Yet this doesn't work:

```
public static class FunctionyStuff {
    public static int RunFunction(this Func<int,int> f, int input) {
        return f(input);
    }
}

// somewhere else in code
Double.RunFunction(5);
```

Any idea why the first one works and the second one doesn't?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first version is performing a *method group conversion* as part of the "argument to parameter" matching. This conversion doesn't happen for extension methods. The same is true for lambda expressions - you couldn't write:

```
((int x) = > x * 2).RunFunction(10);
```

either.

Section 7.6.5.2 of the C# 4 spec gives details of extension method invocations. It starts off by requiring that the method invocation is of one these forms:

```
expr.identifier ( )
expr.identifier ( args )
expr.identifier < typeargs > ( )
expr.identifier < typeargs > ( args )
```

The *type* of the expression (`expr`) is then used in this rule:

> An extension method C<sub>i</sub>.M<sub>j</sub> is *eligible* if
>
> - [...]
> - An implicit identity, reference, or boxing conversion exists from *expr* to the type of the first parameter of M<sub>j</sub>.

The annotated version of the spec then includes this comment from Eric Lippert:

> This rule ensures that making a method that extends `double` does not also extend `int`. It also ensures that no extension methods are defined on anonymous functions or method groups.

Comment: Perhaps you should also explain *why* it doesn’t happen for extension methods and lambda expressions. It’s because they don’t have a specific delegate type. `Func<int, int>` and a hypothetical `MyIntIntDelegate` might have the same signature, but would be different types, so the compiler couldn’t know which one to convert to.

Comment: So if I'm getting this right, in the first version there's an implicit cast from `Method` to `Func`?

Comment: @Joe: It's subtler than that. The method group conversion isn't an identity, reference or boxing conversion. See my edit.

Comment: I think this explanation, while technically fully correct, is very hard to understand for someone who hasn’t read the C# specification. I still think it should mention that “method group” and “anonymous function” are special compile-time types that are *not* automatically delegate types in and of themselves. It could clarify this by showing that you *can* call an extension method on a delegate, e.g. `new Func<int, int>(x => 2*x).MyExtensionMethod()`, to demonstrate that a conversion from the lambda to the delegate type must happen first.

Comment: @Timwi: I would *hope* that someone who's trying to add an extension method to a delegate type already has some idea about what a method group does. Maybe I'm too hopeful though...

Answer (score 0):

[Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) "are called as if they were instance methods on the extended type".

In your case `Double` is not an instance, so you can't call extension method on it.